# WPF DataGrid - Bind EditMode

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid bound to a collection. I would like to enter/leave EditMode for each row with a checkbox (first column of the row). Row is checked, row is in EditMode ...row is unchecked, no edit mode.

How can I achieve my goal ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

as you said you have your datagrid bind to a collection of objects(class with some properties in it) so just made a property iseditable in your class like this..

```
private bool _isEdiatble;
    public bool IsEdiatble
    {
        get
        {
            return _isEdiatble;
        }
        set
        {
            _isEdiatble = value;
            //   FirePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
```

and bind it to your each row element like this..

```
 <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid >
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding text}"  Grid.Column="0" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsEditable}" />
                            <CheckBox Grid.Column="1" IsChecked="{Binding IsEditable,mode=twoway , UpdateSourceTriggered = PropertyChanged }" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

also make sure you have implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged IN your Class ..because it will not work without it..hope you got the point i want to make..for any query comment below..